# What, no warning when minipage overflows page?

Tags: pdftex, minipage, warnings

Instead of complaining about a warning message, I am complaining about lack of a warning message. MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
It was a dark and stormy night.\par
\newpage
% The following lorem ipsum will visually be clipped to one page.
% But the entire text is written into the PDF, mostly hidden.
\begin{minipage}[t][.8\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
First: \lipsum{}\par
Second: \lipsum{}\par
Third: \lipsum{}\par
\end{minipage}
\newpage
And so to bed.\par
\end{document}
```

Above, there is too much text to fit the minipage environment, which will not continue to a next page. In my case, this is the desired behavior, because I am trying to do a vertical clip to remain on one page.

Setting minipage height to less than full textblock height does not clip at the end of minipage. This is surprising, but acceptable here. It does clip at the very bottom of the page MediaBox. However, no warning message appears in the log file! I expected an Overfull vbox warning.

I know that all of the text is written into the PDF, because I can see it all, when the PDF is uncompressed and opened in a hex editor. That means that there is non-printable text, which would cause the PDF to be rejected when scrutinized for standards compliance.

So, my question is: How can I generate at least a logfile Overfull vbox warning message, for the above situation? Or is there something already in the logfile, but I don't know what it means?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is "by design"  the vertical size options of minipage and parbox are analogues (and share the code of) the horizontal size option of `\makebox`.

```
\makebox[0pt][l]{...}
```

hides the size of the content and makes it silently overprint surrounding material.  `\parbox` with `[t]` in the inner alignment is the same.

If you use `s` then you get a warning

```
\begin{minipage}[t][.8\textheight][s]{\textwidth}
```

logs:

```
Overfull \vbox (1188.41469pt too high) detected at line 12
```

But with `s` you are responsible to add stretchable glue to achieve the specified size. If you add glue that will stretch but not shrink you will get warnings for too much material but no warnings for too little.

Comment: where is this behavior (no overfull report) documented?  it's not in the companion ...

Comment: @barbarabeeton not everything that doesn't happen is documented. As I say, it's same as `\makebox` which has been in latex since the beginning.

Comment: I can certainly add stretchable glue, since the minipage in question is entirely under my control. Usage: My final PDF has a mandatory blank page. In draft mode only, I use that page to print certain information. Total quantity of info not known until created. Most important info comes first. OK if less important info gets chopped off. But even the draft is subjected to a test, whcih it won't pass if text overflows the MediaBox (printable area). Nice to have a warning first.

Comment: @RobtA since you follow it anyway with `\newpage` (at least in this example) the vertical height argument isn't doing a lot, you could just let the minipage be natural height and then the page would warn if it was too large

Comment: @David Carlisle: Understood. The 0.8 was just a random try, not of any significance.

Comment: @RobtA yes but what I meant was you only fail to get the overfull warning because of that argument, and just not having the argument at all would be simpler

Comment: @David Carlisle: Ouch! You are right! Eliminating the limiting minipage height does indeed throw the warning. So simple. It did not occur to me that specifying a minipage height limit would make a warning go away. I thought that, if anything, it would make a missing warning appear.

Comment: @RobtA basically it says "I know this stuff is too large but treat it as if it was _this height_  so in many ways its main effect is to suppress the warning.